# Upgrade Access 2000 to 2010 then 2016 VB question

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2016

Help please...I have successfully upgraded from Access 2000 to 2010 then to 2016 with no compile errors however I have an exe file within a form in the VB code and it doesn't run anymore or send an error message.  The project is a weighbridge and has been operating on access 2000 for 15 or more years with many changes to the design, where the exe file captures the data from the weighbridge "signal" box and sends it to my form. This exe no longer works in Access 2010 (the go between program during upgrade) or in Access 2016.  This is crucial to the project, I no longer have the original code in VB or a copy of VB on my computer although I do have a copy in a text file left by the original programmer.  Can anyone tell me Why Access 2016 does not acknowledge this exe.  Is there a reference that needs to be clicked? I am lost.

The code is

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load() 
    On Error GoTo Err_Form1 
    Select Case strDocName 
    Case "GetGrossWeight" 
       Set objFrmCtrl = Forms!ConsignmentsIN.GrossWeight
       Warning.Caption = "Get Gross Weight In"   
    Case "GetTareWeight"
       Set objFrmCtrl = Forms!ConsignmentsContractIN.TareWeight 
       Warning.Caption = "Get Tare Weight In" 
    Case "GetGrossWeightcontract" 
       Set objFrmCtrl = Forms!ConsignmentsContract.GrossWeight
       Warning.Caption = "Get Gross Weight In"   
    Case "GetTareWeight"
       Set objFrmCtrl = Forms!ConsignmentsContract.TareWeight 
       Warning.Caption = "Get Tare Weight In" 
    End Select
    OpenEXE
Exit_Form2:
    Exit Sub
Err_Form1:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Exit_Form2
End Sub

Private Sub OpenEXE() 
    On Error Resume Next 
    GrossValue = Shell("c:\weighbr\auto\Weight.exe", 6) 
    If Err.Number = 53 And GrossValue = 0 Then 
        MsgBox "Can't find program 'Weight.exe'", vbInformation, "Alert" 
    End If 
    ' ...
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "having an exe file within a form"?

Comment: Thanks for replying, this is the Event Procedure which triggers the exe.

Comment: Set objFrmCtrl = Forms!ConsignmentsContract.TareWeight
            Warning.Caption = "Get Tare Weight Out"
            Box54.BackColor = vbRed
    End Select
    OpenEXE
Exit_Form2:
    Exit Sub
Err_Form1:
        MsgBox Error$
        Resume Exit_Form2
End Sub
Private Sub OpenEXE()
On Error Resume Next
    GrossValue = Shell("c:\weighbr\auto\Weight.exe", 6)
    If Err.Number = 53 And GrossValue = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Can't find program 'Weight.exe'", vbInformation, "Alert"
End If

Comment: Sorry, I tried to paste the information and it hasn't worked very well.

Comment: Best if you edit your question

Comment: It starts with Private Sub Form_Load() On Error GoTo Err_Form1  Select Case strDocName  Case "GetGrossWeight"

Comment: This question can probably be best answered if is moved to StackOverflow. It actually doesn't involve database design, but **programming** using Access and VBA.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for `SHELL`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Shell-Function-ff2e4b1b-712d-4e34-aea6-6832eadd3c63?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1):

> Runs an executable program and returns a Variant (Double) representing the program's task ID if successful, otherwise it returns zero.

Your code gets a `task ID`, not the result of executing the .exe program (if nothng else prevents execution). So, you shouldn't expect, in any case, to get a value generated by this program.

You should use the debugging tools to step into this `Sub` and actually figure out what it does.

Check if [Alternative to Call Shell() ? (2000)](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/59809-Alternative-to-Call-Shell()-(2000)) can help you out, and also [Access 2000 to 2002 (Shell command)](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=374602).

It seems that the Shell function might have changed a looong time ago.

Comment: I have stepped through the program and in 2016 it gets to the exe but continues on as if it wasn't there, the result being blank.  I shall do some more research on what you have given me. Thanks for being patient.  My Access 2000 MDB always returns a result ie if nothing on the weighbridge then I get a Zero but 2016 results in blank. Thanks again

Comment: What if there *is* something on the weighbridge?

Comment: Works perfectly in Access 2000 in the mdb database when something is on the bridge  dumps the displayed weight  into my form but when I updated to Access 2016 (via 2010) it doesn't register anything...any ideas?

Comment: perhaps you running the x64 bit version of Access? I would check and ensure that you are running x32 version